# Multiple dynamic sort values in lambda

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, mapping

I can sort an array by mapping. But how can i build the lambda for a unknown count of dynamic maps in s?

```
l = ['1','2','3']
s = [{ '3':'a', '2':'a', '1':'c'},{ '3':'z', '2':'a', '1':'b'},{ '1':34, '2':123, '3':1000}]

sorted(l, key=lambda x: (s[0][x], s[1][x], s[2][x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, why hardcoding this when you can iterate on `s` and create the key using list comprehension:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: [p[x] for p in s])
```

(note that now key is a `list`, no longer a `tuple` but that doesn't matter since they share the same ordering)

Comment: Sometimes things are so simple :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort in an arbitrary number of parameters using comparator like so:

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key
l = ['1','2','3']
s = [{ '3':'a', '2':'a', '1':'c'},{ '3':'z', '2':'a', '1':'b'},{ '1':34, '2':123, '3':1000}]

def compare(x,y):
    for dc in s:
        if dc[x] < dc[y]:
            return -1
        elif dc[x] > dc[y]:
            return 1
    return 0
sorted(l, key= cmp_to_key(compare))
```

There's no need to use lambda function for this one.